How to vectorize Jacobi elliptic function calls in python with negative arguments
I've got a differential equation which I have solved exactly in terms of Jacobi elliptic functions. Now I'd like to efficiently evaluate the (exact) solution numerically for the sake of plotting and some further numerical analysis. The solutions I have found to do this in python either seem to (1) apply to my case and be rather inefficient or (2) not apply to the specific parameters of my problem but would be efficient if they were available.
The first set of functions I've tried are in numpy with documentation here. As stated there, these functions take two arguments u and m with the restriction that 0<m<1. Formally however these functions are defined mathematically for negative m as well, which happens to describe the case I'm interested in. This is unfortunate because the numpy implementation seems fast.
Next I tried the mpmath functions described here, which do the job but are slow compared to the numpy functions. The mpmath functions do not seem to be vectorizable, which is why I say they're slow. Making a vectorized function with np.vectorize() seems to be even slower than the mpmath functions.
Perhaps there's a good computational reason that computing the Jacobi elliptic functions for negative m is more challenging but I'm not sure.
Is there a library or some python resource which can handle this case and does so in an efficient manner? Waiting around for numerical results when I have a closed form function is painful.

np.vectorize does not actually vectorize the function based on the definition provided by Numpy developers themself. This function has a very bad name. To quote the doc : "the vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop."

If the items you want to compute are CPython objects (including functions), so not native integers/FP-numbers, then there is no way to vectorize operations unless the library providing the object also provide the function you want.

I wish they renamed vectorize to "map" or "forloopize" or whatever. The number of times it confuses people is appalling...   Anyway, maybe try to ask mpmath author on his github about performance? But first, check if similar question is not present and prepare minimal reproducible example to save his time to understand what you are doing.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
